# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing an error while grouping a statement. Here is my code

```
 DECLARE @avg_volume INT
 SELECT @avg_volume = ISNULL(AVG(Total_Volume), 0)
 FROM   ( SELECT    station_id ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) AS YEAR ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) AS MONTH ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) AS DATE ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time) AS weekday ,
                    SUM(volume) AS Total_volume
          FROM      rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
          GROUP BY  station_id ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time)
        )
 GROUP BY station_id ,
        CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
        DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
        DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
        DATENAME(weekday, date_time)
 ORDER BY DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
        DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
        CONVERT(DATE, date_time)

 SELECT @avg_volume
```

What I am trying to do is ,taking the sum from volume group by a set of conditions(Inner query), which will give result as

```
station_id  YEAR    MONTH   DATE            weekday Total_volume
7       2013    2   2013-02-21  Thursday    192
7       2013    2   2013-02-27  Wednesday   2699
7       2013    2   2013-02-28  Thursday    196
2       2013    3   2013-03-07  Thursday    192
7       2013    3   2013-03-07  Thursday    192
```

now I want to take average of that. Any assistance will be helpful.

My Table primary table

```
station_id  date_time   volume

7   2013-02-21 00:00:00.000 96
7   2013-02-21 01:00:00.000 96
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 356
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 410
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 471
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 530
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 338
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 211
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 159
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 128
7   2013-02-27 00:00:00.000 96
7   2013-02-28 00:00:00.000 96
7   2013-02-28 01:00:00.000 100
7   2013-03-07 00:00:00.000 96
2   2013-03-07 00:00:00.000 96
2   2013-03-07 01:00:00.000 96
7   2013-03-07 01:00:00.000 96
```

Desired Output :

```
station id     year  month     weekday    average_volume
  7            2013     2      Thursday     194
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to name your subquery:

```
DECLARE @avg_volume INT
 SELECT @avg_volume = ISNULL(AVG(Total_Volume), 0)
 FROM   ( SELECT    station_id ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) AS YEAR ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) AS MONTH ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) AS DATE ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time) AS weekday ,
                    SUM(volume) AS Total_volume
          FROM      rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
          GROUP BY  station_id ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time)

        ) AnyNameYouLikeButYouHaveToGiveOne --<-- Here

 GROUP BY station_id ,
        CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
        DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
        DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
        DATENAME(weekday, date_time)
 ORDER BY DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
        DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
        CONVERT(DATE, date_time)

 SELECT @avg_volume
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few fundamental issues in your query. You are summing up and finding average on basis of month year Date ETC. I do not see any filters, for a year  or month or an station id. So I assume there will be more than one row in your final select query and you are selecting into a variable. So you may get only the value from the first/last row in the variable(Of course depending on the ordering) .You have to make some  modification to the query here.

Is this query giving you correct output?

```
SELECT  ISNULL(AVG(Total_volume), 0)
FROM    ( SELECT    station_id ,
                    DATEPART(year, date_time) AS YEAR ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) AS MONTH ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) AS DATE ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time) AS weekday ,
                    SUM(volume) AS Total_volume
          FROM      rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
          GROUP BY  station_id ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(year, date_time) ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time)
          ORDER BY  DATEPART(year, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time)
        ) T;
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'date_time'. This is what am getting when i run your query , Note : i have that column with the same name @sathesh

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want to do, you don't need to do a second explicit aggregation or `order by`.  Just take the average:

```
DECLARE @avg_volume INT
SELECT  @avg_volume = ISNULL(AVG(Total_Volume), 0)
FROM    ( SELECT    station_id ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) AS "YEAR" ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) AS "MONTH" ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) AS "date" ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time) AS weekday ,
                    SUM(volume) AS Total_volume
          FROM      rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
          GROUP BY  station_id ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time)
        ) t;
```

Your specific error was because you had no alias on the subquery (well, the keyword `group` doesn't count as an alias).

Some of your column names a keywords, so I quoted those.  The list of such words is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

Actually, when writing a query like this, you don't need to include all the columns in the `select`, so you could also do:

```
DECLARE @avg_volume INT
SELECT  @avg_volume = ISNULL(AVG(Total_Volume), 0)
FROM    ( SELECT    SUM(volume) AS Total_volume
          FROM      rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
          GROUP BY  station_id ,
                    CONVERT(DATE, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(month, date_time) ,
                    DATEPART(Year, date_time) ,
                    DATENAME(weekday, date_time)
        ) t;
```

Comment: What i am trying to do is taking the sum of values from volume column which contains data per hour..so am taking the sum of it grouped by year,month,station and weekday...Then i ll get the desired sum of volume as per my requirement . Now what i need to do is taking the average out of it .Like average of all volume for all thursday's in a month .