# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' IN SQL while taking average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing an error while grouping the following statement. Here is my code

```
DECLARE @avg_volume int
SELECT @avg_volume=ISNULL(AVG(Total_Volume),0)
FROM
  (SELECT station_id,
          DATEPART(YEAR,date_time) AS YEAR,
          DATEPART(MONTH,date_time) AS MONTH,
          CONVERT(date,date_time) AS DATE,
          DATENAME(weekday,date_time) AS weekday,
          sum(volume) AS Total_volume
   FROM rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
   GROUP BY station_id,
            CONVERT(date,date_time),
            DATEPART(MONTH,date_time),
            DATEPART(YEAR,date_time),
            DATENAME(weekday,date_time))
GROUP BY station_id,
         CONVERT(date,date_time),
         DATEPART(MONTH,date_time),
         DATEPART(YEAR,date_time),
         DATENA ME(weekday,date_time)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,date_time),
         DATEPART(MONTH,date_time),
         CONVERT(date,date_time)
SELECT @avg_volume
```

My inner query will return

```
station_id  YEAR    MONTH    DATE       weekday Total_volume
7           2013    2       2013-02-21  Thursday    192
7           2013    2       2013-02-27  Wednesday   2699
7           2013    2       2013-02-28  Thursday    196
2           2013    3       2013-03-07  Thursday    192
7           2013    3       2013-03-07  Thursday    192
```

My primary table is :

```
station_id  date_time             volume

7       2013-02-21 00:00:00.000   96
7       2013-02-21 01:00:00.000   96
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   356
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   410
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   471
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   530
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   338
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   211
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   159
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   128
7       2013-02-27 00:00:00.000   96
7       2013-02-28 00:00:00.000   96
7       2013-02-28 01:00:00.000   100
7       2013-03-07 00:00:00.000   96
2       2013-03-07 00:00:00.000   96
2       2013-03-07 01:00:00.000   96
7       2013-03-07 01:00:00.000   96
```

**My desired output is:**

```
station id     year  month     weekday    average_volume
  7            2013     2      Thursday     194
```

Comment: what is this:   DATENA    ME(weekday,date_time)

Comment: Why are you asking another question which is exactly sames as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085998/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-group-in-sql).

Comment: Where did your station id 2 go ? where did your Wednesday disappeared?

Comment: Just bcz i havent got the answer..simple @raging

Comment: @bibinmatthew: It doesn't mean you should post another question, does it? When you post a question give it some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 issues in query you have posted:

1. As pointed by everyone correct identifier DATENA ME to `DATENAME`.
2. When a inner query in defined in `From` clause of an outer query it is actually a `'Derived Table'`.Their scope of existence is the outer query. As soon as the outer query is finished, the derived table is gone. So we need to specify the query that defines the   derived table within parentheses, followed by the AS clause and the derived table name. (Below I have written it as `'T'`)
3. Now as we are referring to columns from a derived table in outer query only the columns defined in it can be accessed. ( So I have corrected the outer query columns)

Write as:

```
--DECLARE @avg_volume int
SELECT ISNULL(AVG(Total_Volume),0) as average_volume,
         station_id,
         MONTH,
         YEAR,
         weekday
FROM
  (SELECT station_id,
          DATEPART(YEAR,date_time) AS YEAR,
          DATEPART(MONTH,date_time) AS MONTH,
          CONVERT(date,date_time) AS DATE,
          DATENAME(weekday,date_time) AS weekday,
          sum(volume) AS Total_volume
   FROM rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly
   GROUP BY station_id,
            CONVERT(date,date_time),
            DATEPART(MONTH,date_time),
            DATEPART(YEAR,date_time),
            DATENAME(weekday,date_time)) AS T
WHERE WEEKDAY = 'Thursday' AND MONTH=2
GROUP BY station_id,
         MONTH,
         YEAR,
         weekday
ORDER BY YEAR,
         MONTH
```

SQL FIDDLE:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6217d/10

Comment: Still i didnt got the desired output :(

Comment: @deepshika : what you were trying to do? Just run the inner query and the whole..both returns the same :-/

Comment: edited the query check now..

Comment: @deepshika: using a where condition it can be done, what if i have data for other week days? I need to group it by weekdays right, i was giving a example. Average of volume per weekdays in a month and year..

Comment: So..removing where condition will solve your problem isn't it??

Comment: Yes (y) ,Thanks alot friend :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in your code `DATENAME`

```
DATENA ME(weekday,date_time)
```

Write as

```
DATENAME(weekday,date_time)
```

------------------------Another point--------------------------

you must use name for for your subquery like

```
SELECT t1.yourColumn
(
select yourColumn
FROM tableABC
) t1 <you not assign name here to newly subquery created table e.g t1>
```

Also use column aliases like

```
SELECT t1.aliasName
(
select yourColumn as [aliasName] 
FROM tableABC
) t1
ORDER BY t1.aliasName
```

Comment: just a mistake while  copying..shabbaa :(

Answer (score 0):

Give alias name to your inner query and then make use of that alias name in your outer table group by statement

```
(select 
     station_id,  
     DATEPART(Year,date_time) AS YEAR,  
     DATEPART(month,date_time) AS MONTH,  
     CONVERT(date,date_time) AS DATE,  
     DATENAME(weekday,date_time) as weekday,  
     sum(volume) AS Total_volume  
 from rvtcs_data_aggregated_hourly   
 group by   
     station_id,
     CONVERT(date,date_time),
     DATEPART(month,date_time),  
     DATEPART(Year,date_time),
     DATENAME(weekday,date_time)
) AS MYJUNCTIONTABLE
```

Also I found spaces between DATE NA ME while copying your code, see its corrected above.